# Issue making API call from from React context in nested providers

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created 2 contexts in my react app. The first is the App Provider that has auth functions for API calls to login, logout, register, and update. It also has an authFetch function in it to check if the user is authorized. The second context is the Study Provider that is going to handle dealing with study material. You also need to be authorized to use it so I was trying to import the authFetch function into the study provider.

However, that doesn't seem to work. It will only return an empty array and the state isn't updated. The appContext file works fine and if I paste the fetchQuestions into the appContext file, it will make the API call. However, it is just not working in the studyContext file.

Is there something I am missing to be able to use the authFetch function in the fetchQuestions function? Is there a better way to write this code or refactor it?

React dom

```xml
<React.StrictMode>
    <AppProvider>
      <StudyProvider>
        <App />
      </StudyProvider>
    </AppProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
```

studyContext.js

```
import { useReducer, useContext, createContext, useEffect } from 'react'
import * as actionTypes from './studyActionTypes'
import { useAppContext } from '../appContext'

const initialState = {
  questions: [],
  error: null
}

const StudyContext = createContext()

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.FETCH_QUESTIONS:
      return {
        ...state,
        questions: action.payload,
        isLoading: false,
        error: null
      }
    default:
      throw new Error(`Unknown action type: ${action.type}`)
  }
}

const StudyProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const { authFetch } = useAppContext()
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)

  const fetchQuestions = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await authFetch.get('/questions')
      const questions = data

      dispatch({
        type: actionTypes.FETCH_QUESTIONS,
        payload: questions
      })

      console.log(state.questions)
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: actionTypes.FETCH_QUESTIONS,
        payload: [],
        error: error.message
      })
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchQuestions()
  }, [])

  return (
    <StudyContext.Provider
      value={{
        ...state,
        fetchQuestions
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </StudyContext.Provider>
  )
}

const useStudyContext = () => {
  return useContext(StudyContext)
}

export { StudyProvider, useStudyContext }
```

appContext.js

```
import { useReducer, useContext, createContext } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import * as actionTypes from './actionTypes'

const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
const user = localStorage.getItem('user')

const initialState = {
  isLoading: false,
  showAlert: false,
  alertText: '',
  alertType: '',
  user: user ? JSON.parse(user) : null,
  token: token
}

const AppContext = createContext()

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.DISPLAY_ALERT:
      return {
        ...state,
        showAlert: false,
        alertType: '',
        alertText: ''
      }
    case actionTypes.REGISTER:
    case actionTypes.LOGIN:
      return {
        ...state,
        token: action.payload.token,
        user: action.payload.user
      }
    case actionTypes.LOGOUT:
      return {
        ...initialState,
        user: null,
        token: null
      }
    case actionTypes.UPDATE_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        token: action.payload.token,
        user: action.payload.user
      }
    default:
      throw new Error(`Unknown action type: ${action.type}`)
  }
}

const AppProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)

  // Axios
  const authFetch = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'api/v1'
  })

  // Request
  authFetch.interceptors.request.use(
    (config) => {
      config.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${state.token}`
      return config
    },
    (error) => {
      return Promise.reject(error)
    }
  )

  // Response
  authFetch.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
      return response
    },
    (error) => {
      if (error.response.status === 401) {
        logout()
      }
      return Promise.reject(error)
    }
  )

  const displayAlert = () => {
    dispatch({ type: actionTypes.DISPLAY_ALERT })
  }

  const addUserToLocalStorage = ({ user, token }) => {
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user))
    localStorage.setItem('token', token)
  }

  const removeUserFromLocalStorage = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem('user')
    localStorage.removeItem('token')
  }

  const registerUser = async (currentUser) => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.post('/api/v1/auth/register', currentUser)
      const { user, token } = data

      dispatch({
        type: actionTypes.REGISTER,
        payload: { user, token }
      })

      addUserToLocalStorage({ user, token })
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(error.response.data.msg)
    }
  }

  const login = async (currentUser) => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.post('/api/v1/auth/login', currentUser)
      const { user, token } = data

      dispatch({
        type: actionTypes.LOGIN,
        payload: { user, token }
      })

      addUserToLocalStorage({ user, token })
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(error.response.data.msg)
    }
  }

  const logout = () => {
    try {
      dispatch({ type: actionTypes.LOGOUT })
      removeUserFromLocalStorage()
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(error)
    }
  }

  const updateUser = async (currentUser) => {
    try {
      const { data } = await authFetch.patch('/auth/updateUser', currentUser)
      const { user, token } = data

      dispatch({ type: actionTypes.UPDATE_USER, payload: { user, token } })
      addUserToLocalStorage({ user, token })
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(error.response.data.msg)
    }
  }

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider
      value={{
        ...state,
        displayAlert,
        registerUser,
        login,
        logout,
        updateUser
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  )
}

const useAppContext = () => {
  return useContext(AppContext)
}

export { AppProvider, useAppContext }
```

Comment: In fetchQuestions, try remove `const questions = data` and pass `data` into dispatch payload instead of `questions`